# Handsontable issue. Dropdown moves one line down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handsontable

I have this simple table.

[image: I have this table]

But when i force an error on it this happen. My dropdown moves down the line.

[image]

And my css adds a height that you cant delete with nothing, i have tried deleting from console, jquery, even forcing with important.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating this issue so we can poke around? It would seem like giving the htAutocompleteArrow a fixed width and using white-space: no-wrap; should resolve the problem, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Would be really hard, because i have combined ajax with django for showing the data =/